# Django - Follow a backward ForeignKey and then a ForeignKey (query)

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I use Django 1.9 and Python 2.7.

My app has four models. Each "trip" is made of several "steps" chosen by the visitor, which relate to "places", which may have several related "Picture".

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

class Step(models.Model):
    theplace = models.ForeignKey(ThePlace)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)

class ThePlace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Picture(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    theplace = models.ForeignKey(ThePlace, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to retrieve all "Picture" objects which are related to a specific Trip, using an existing "selectedtrip" queryset:

```
selectedtrip = Trip.objects.filter(author=request.user)[0]
pictures = selectedtrip.step_set.all().theplace.picture_set.all()
```

Django displays the following error:
"AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'theplace'"
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `all()` returns a queryset, which is a collection of items; `theplace` is an attribute on an individual Step, not on the collection.

The way to do this type of query is to start from the class you want to retrieve, and follow the relationships within the query using the double-underscore syntax. So:

```
Picture.objects.filter(theplace__step__trip=selectedtrip)
```